# download pdf from a web page's html using vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pdf

In my application, there is an option to download pdf using URL input of same domain(intranet site). There are 3 pages in my application(http://example.com/about, http://example.com/home, http://example.com/htmltopdf)

In htmltopdf page, there is a text input field and button download pdf. If we give input url (http://example.com/about), It should download pdf of about page's html. For this, i have tried couple of things but it is converting pdf from the index.html of public folder.

I am using vue js in my application and i have tried like this

**Approach -1**

```
    downloadHtml() {
  let url = this.urlInput;  // input text v-model value
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((html) => this.downloadAsFile("report.pdf", html)); // by this name it is downloading
},
downloadAsFile(name, text) {
  const link = this.createDownloadableLink(name, text);
  const clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click");
  link.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
},
createDownloadableLink(fileName, content) {
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = `data:attachment/text,${content}' + encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.download = fileName;
  return link;
},
```

**Approach -2** (based on answer of another post)

```
    async fetchHTML() {
   let url = this.urlInput
let content = await fetch(url).then(resp => resp.text());

let file = new Blob([content],{type:'text/html'});
let href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
let a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = href;
a.setAttribute('download', 'report.pdf');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));

}
```

For these two approaches, it is downloading the pdf of public/index.html not the actual one. After checking or searching more, i got some suggestions to use puppeteer or nuxt.js for this downloading pdf but i didn't get that any example for this scenario. I am not sure how to do this function workable in vue.js platform or how to use puppeteer in vue.js?

**I have checked vue-htmltopdf npm package but how to send URL directly there to download pdf?**

Please give me suggestion or example how to download pdf from given URL input of same domain?

Comment: i think you need a library or sth. to archive this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Can you give any example?

Comment: no sorry. never did it. google sth like "html2pdf js" etc.

Comment: maybe this on https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js

Comment: Thanks for this. But, how to pass the URL i didn't get it??